# Is it possible to override find(sequence, element) function in swift?

Tags: swift

I have an array of MyObject where my object is like this:

```
class MyObject: Equatable {
   var name: String?
   var age: Int?

   init(name: String, age: Int) {
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
   }
}

func ==(first: MyObject, second: MyObject) -> Bool {
    return first.name == second.name
}
```

Let's say my array is:

```
var array: [MyObject]
```

Is there a way to use find(sequence, element) function like this? :

```
var myFoundObject = find(array, "name_of_the_object_I_m_looking_for")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kirsteins mentioned, `find` returns the index.

You can easily implement your own `find` which accept testing function, like `filter`:

```
func find<C:CollectionType, U where C.Generator.Element == U>(domain:C, isValue:U -> Bool) -> C.Index? {
    for idx in indices(domain) {
        if isValue(domain[idx]) {
            return idx
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// usage
let array = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
if let found = find(array, { $0.hasSuffix("az") }) {
    let obj = array[found]
}
```

Using this, you can:

```
if let found = find(array, { $0.name == "name_of_the_object_I_m_looking_for" }) {
    let myFoundObject = array[found]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rintaro but I get a "Could not find member 'name'" error when I write: if let found = find(array, { $0.name == "name_of_the_object_I_m_looking_for" }) {
    let myFoundObject = array[found]
}

Comment: All good, I didn't called the right find function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`find` function returns the index of object in collection, not the object.

You have to iterate ovre array to find the object that matches you criteria, for example:

```
var myObject: MyObject? = {
    for object in array {
        if "name_of_the_object_I_m_looking_for" == object.name {
            return object
        }
    }

    return nil
}()
```

Comment: Thanks @Kirsteins. I thought about iterating the array but was wondering if it was possible to override find()

Comment: Override doesn't change the signature of the method. You can only override methods of superclass. `find` is standalone function not associated with any type. You can change the signature of method like in @rintaro answer. That is called (method/function) overloading.